# Automatically change gateway based on internet connection

Tags: networking, debian, internet, ethernet, gateway

I have 2 connections to different internet providers in my Debian 11 system, I need to set the eth0 as the default and if it loses internet for any reason, change to eth1. After that if eth0 gets internet back I will need to get that connection as the main again. Is that possible?

Comment: Use a router that can do that?

Comment: I would like to learn how can I accomplish that in Debian because I don't know how to do that with a router either

Comment: Not a learning place. THis is a place or professionals.

Answer (score 2):

Yes this can be done using the network management tools of Debian

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ifmetric iproute2
```

---

Create a systemd service `/etc/systemd/system/switch-internet.service`

---

```
[Unit]
Description=Switch Internet Connection

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/path/to/your/script.sh
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

---

Create a script and save where you prefer

`/path/to/your/script.sh`

---

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
    # Check eth0 connectivity
    if ping -I eth0 -c 1 google.com &> /dev/null; then
        ifmetric eth0 0  # Set lower metric to prioritize eth0
        ifmetric eth1 1
    else
        ifmetric eth0 1  # Set higher metric to deprioritize eth0
        ifmetric eth1 0
    fi
    sleep 10  # Adjust the sleep interval as needed
done
```

---

Enable and start the services

```
sudo systemctl enable switch-internet.service
sudo systemctl start switch-internet.service
```

Comment: I would in general suggest *some* delays. `while true` may come back to bite you, for instance if all connections are down, so ping never works, but fails fast. `while sleep 1` is probably better. Furthermore this will only affect new connections.

Comment: @vidarlo Feel free to edit my answer whenever you think it's needed